# Dynamically change dependent variable in formula

Tags: r

I have a dependent variable name list as

```
depend<-c('a', 'b', 'c')
```

And I have a formula for regression model can be defined as

```
1_equ<-d~e
```

I would like to automatically switch the dependent variable of that formula by using update.

I have tried

```
for ( i in depend) { 
  equ_name<-assign(paste0("1_equ_", i), depend[i])
  equ_name<-update(1_equ, paste(depend[i]) ~ .)
  }
```

Seems like it does not work, it only extract the string, but could not switch the variable.

The print results are

```
chr NA
```

I would like three outpus:

```
1_equ_a: a~e
1_equ_b: b~e
1_equ_c: c~e
```

Comment: If a, b and c are existing objects in your environment. why not just create a list rather than a vector and reference the variables you want to use by their list index?  e.g. depend <- list(a, b, c).  Then reference depend[[1]], depend[[2]], depend[[3]] however you want.

Comment: Use `reformulate`

Comment: @IRTFM post that as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

It would need the `"~ ."` in quotes along with loop over the sequence of 'vector' elements and as the object name starts with a digit, use backquotes around it

```
`1_equ` <- d ~ e
for ( i in seq_along(depend)) { 
  nm1 <- paste0("1_equ_", depend[i])  
  
  assign(nm1, update(`1_equ`, paste(depend[i],  "~ .")))
  }
```

-output

```
> `1_equ_a`
a ~ e
> `1_equ_b`
b ~ e
> `1_equ_c`
c ~ e
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1: construct a formula manually using `call`

You can do this without string processing with `paste` by manually constructing a formula object from symbols using `call`:

```r
depend <- c("a", "b", "c")

fmla <- d ~ x + y + z
print(fmla)

for (depvar in depend) { 
  fmla <- update(fmla, call("~", as.symbol(depvar), as.symbol(".")))
  print(fmla)
}

# d ~ x + y + z
# a ~ x + y + z
# b ~ x + y + z
# c ~ x + y + z
```

And this can be wrapped up nicely in a function:

```r
replace_dependent <- function(fmla, new_var) {
  pattern <- call("~", as.symbol(new_var), as.symbol("."))
  update(fmla, pattern)
}

depend <- c("a", "b", "c")

fmla <- d ~ x + y + z
print(fmla)

for (depvar in depend) { 
  fmla <- replace_dependent(fmla, depvar)
  print(fmla)
}

# d ~ x + y + z
# a ~ x + y + z
# b ~ x + y + z
# c ~ x + y + z
```

I personally much prefer working with `call` and other "syntactic" objects, instead of constructing and parsing strings.

---

## Solution 2: use `reformulate`

An even tidier solution was suggested by [IRTFM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855677/irtfm) in the comments: use `reformulate`.

```r
extract_term_labels <- function(fmla) {
  attr(terms(fmla), "term.labels")
}

replace_dependent <- function(fmla, new_var) {
  reformulate(extract_term_labels(fmla), new_var, env = parent.frame(2))
}

depend <- c("a", "b", "c")

fmla <- d ~ x + y + z
print(fmla)

for (depvar in depend) { 
  fmla <- replace_dependent(fmla, depvar)
  print(fmla)
}

# d ~ x + y + z
# a ~ x + y + z
# b ~ x + y + z
# c ~ x + y + z
```

Note the use of `env = parent.frame(2)` to prevent accidentally creating a closure over the internal environment of the `replace_dependent()` function.